# DBGrid Highlighting the located row via code?

Tags: delphi, row, highlighting, tdbgrid

I got the : 
  ADOTable1 ( codepeople as integer, namepeople as string ) 
  DataSource1 ( the DateSet is ADOTable1 )
  DBGrid1 ( connected to DataSource1, Options-dgRowSelect is true )

I locate a row on ADOTable1 with the following code

```
  ADOTable1.Locate(ADOTable11codepeople.FieldName, 1, []);
```

DBGrid1 is selecting the correct row. But not with the highlights.

How to make the DBGrid automatically highlights the row that I located from ADOTable1 ?

I read the following links and did not find the answer :

[How to set active cell in TDBGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978780/how-to-set-active-cell-in-tdbgrid/8164575#8164575)

[Delphi - Using DBGrid to select rows from a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744841/delphi-using-dbgrid-to-select-rows-from-a-search)

[View position in DBGrid when scrolling in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335526/view-position-in-dbgrid-when-scrolling-in-delphi)

Simple source code please...

PS:  I use Delphi 2010.

Comment: if Option `dgAlwaysShowSelection` should not be what you are looking for then the answer of the last link you posted should cover your demands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, After I tried myself, then I findout that the code below can do the code :

```
DBGrid1.setfocus;
```

Since the row already correctly selected, the setfocus help the highlight to come up.

Anyway, thanks for the replies :)

Comment: you can elso set TabOrder of DBGrid in Object Inspector to **0** .note : i use embarcadero XE7

Answer (score 6):

The following code will cause the selected row in a grid to be highlighted

```
type
 THackDBGrid = class (TDBGrid);

...

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
           const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
           State: TGridDrawState);
begin
 if (THackDBGrid(dbGrid1).DataLink.ActiveRecord + 1 = THackDBGrid(dbGrid1).Row)
  or (gdFocused in State) or (gdSelected in State) then
   dbGrid1.canvas.Brush.Color:= clMoneyGreen;


 dbGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell (Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Comment: THIS is the best answer. It's 2021 and I'm in Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo). More on this in my (expanded answer below).

Comment: I also found this useful: http://www.delphigroups.info/2/aa/351370.html

Delphi 7. Note that to get this method, go to the grid and double click on the OnDrawDataCell event.

Answer (score 1):

grid.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
This helped me to highlight the current row

Answer (score 1):

answered Oct 27 '13 at 5:44

IMHO, No'am Newman's answer (two above here) is THE BEST, THE CORRECT ANSWER.

It's 2021. I'm in Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo); VCL program. I've been with Delphi since version 3.02 (1986).

Some further explanation:

(1) dgAlwaysShowSelection doesn't work with dgRowSelect (and the links mentioned in this response just overcomplicate - if they work at all)

(2) DBGrid1.SetFocus moves the focus away from whatever might be the ActiveControl

(3) grid.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True; doesn't work for me

(4) No'am's hack --> it's less than 10 lines of code and adds the ability to choose a color.

(4.1) If you don't want to "choose" a color, I'd suggest clGradientActiveCaption (as opposed to No'am's clMoneyGreen).

(*) I am 98% (99%?) sure that all my points above would/will apply to any version of Delphi going back to at least 5.

<that's all I got>

Comment: First Delphi was released 1995! I guess, you mean TurboPascal?

Comment: Yes. TurboPascal 3.02

Answer (score 0):

As an even further extension to No'am Newman's great answer (even in 2022), the following code will cause the selected row in a grid to be highlighted, but with respect to the current scheme using DrawCellHighlight() instead of a particular color:

```
[...]
 If (THackDBGrid(dbGrid1).DataLink.ActiveRecord + 1 = THackDBGrid(dbGrid1).Row)
    or (gdFocused in State) or (gdSelected in State) then
  dbGrid1.DrawCellHighlight(Rect, State, Column.Index, 0);
[...]
```